# how to use the new insertCSS and removeCSS in manifiest v3

Tags: javascript, css, manifest, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

how to use the new insertCSS and removeCSS in manifiest v3?
the docs don't help me and didn't give some example on that.

I have a CSS file that I want to inject it in the page and remove it

the code something like this:

### background.js

```js
document.getElementById('chat').addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  var chat = e.path[0].value;
  // inject css file
  let css = document.createElement('link');
  css.rel = 'stylesheet';
  css.type = 'text/css';
  css.href = 'css/chat-rtl.css';

  if (chat == 'rtl') {
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({ injection: { css } }); // i know it is wrong syntax
    console.log('rtl');
  } else {
    chrome.scripting.removeCSS({ injection: { css } }); // i know it is wrong syntax
    console.log('ltr');
  }
});
```

### error log:

> Uncaught TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.removeCSS(scripting.CSSInjection injection, optional function callback): Error at parameter 'injection': Unexpected property: 'injection'.
> at HTMLSelectElement. (background.js:10:22)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it!

The right syntax was to use `insertCSS` is:

```js
chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
  target: { tabId: tab.id },
  files: ['css/chat-rtl.css'],
});
```

and to get `tab` make the function Asynchronous function and use:

```js
const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
```

### code

```js
document.getElementById('chat').addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
  var chat = e.path[0].value;
  // inject css file

  const [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });

  if (chat == 'rtl') {
    chrome.scripting.insertCSS({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      files: ['css/chat-rtl.css'],
    });
    console.log('rtl');
  } else {
    chrome.scripting.removeCSS({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      files: ['css/chat-ltr.css'],
    });
    console.log('ltr');
  }
});
```

Comment: For future readers, this is documented at [`.insertCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/insertCSS) and [`.removeCSS()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/removeCSS).